# Can't access to dualboot menu?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, bios

i'm trying to install a dualboot with windows 10 and ubuntu in my laptop, i can install the OS successfully but it always load windows as default without showing the boot menu. I did this steps already trying to resolve this problem:

- Changed ubuntu priority to the first position in the boot menu on the BIOS Settings
- Disabled the fast startup in windows and the hibernate options
- Installed the boot setup in the C disk, when it didn't work, i installed directly in the boot partition of windows
- Changed the \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi but it was worse: i wasn't able to boot into windows neither so i had to restore to a previous point.
- Tried to force load from the boot menu (F12) but it says Boot Device not found and force the restart into windows.

My laptop specs:

- Dell Inspiron 15 700 2-in-1 (2019)
- Windows version: Windows 10 Home edition version 2004 for x64 (KB4576478)
- Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 20.04 lts x64
- BIOS version: Dell Inc. 1.10.0, 8/13/2020
- Disk Original Partition:

  - 650Mb EFI System Partition (tried to install the boot here whe it didn't work in the C disk)
  - 360Gb C:/ disk (BitLocker encrypted. Boot, page file,crash dump,basic data partition)
  - 990Mb windows recovery partition
  - 1.2Gb dell support - 13Gb image recovery partition

Has anyone been through something similar to this?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: What you need is a boot manager, Unfortunally windows does not have one. 
Install Windows as your first OS, Then install Ubuntu. 
Ubuntu should take over the boot process, but the GRU Bootloader should automatically give you a option of windows 10 if you installed Ubuntu and selected the Install along side windows 10.

Comment: Hi Dave! thanks for your reply. My first OS is actually Windows, is the OS that my laptop came installed with. I'm trying now to install Ubuntu as my sencond OS but the Grub loader doesn't show up no matter what i try. I'm starting to think like eve wang, that my efi file needs to be repair

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable secure boot in BIOS setting.

Then go to UEFI boot order option, select the linux system.

Check the Linux system if it displays on the top boot loader in Windows boot manager. Then press F10 to save.

Meanwile, I used a tool named EasyBCD before. It will always help to repair boot file. So you could edit your Boot Menu with EasyBCD. If you could not see the dual menu after change BIOS. I consider that you may need to repair boot file.

Comment: Hi eve wang, thnx a lot for your reply. I already di all that. Secure boot disable, but the Ubuntu boot is show apart from the windows boot manager, i actually has 3 options in the UEFI Boot Menu: Ubuntu, Windows Boot Manager and UEFI Boot Disk (i tried to diasble the last one and my laptop didn't boot, so i guess thats the boot that actually works) I tried to install there the ubuntu boot system with no success

I'll try to fix my boot file then. Thnx a lot